# с++ fstream считывает каждый второй байт с бинарного файла

Tags: c++, fstream, binary, byte, buffer

Поток fstream почему-то считывает только каждый второй байт с бинарного файла. Почему так происходит?

```
std::ifstream file("../data/data.BIT", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    unsigned char current_bite;
    const int number_of_bits = 8;
    int step = 0; 
    while (file >> current_bite) {  
        file.read((char*)&current_bite, sizeof(current_bite));
        std::bitset<8>buffer(current_bite);
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_bits; ++i) {
            bit_buffer.emplace_back(buffer[i]);
            std::cout << buffer[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << "byte number = " << step <<'\n';
        step++;
        if (step == 39) {
            break;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    std::cout << bit_buffer.size();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим:

```
while (file >> current_bite) {  
    file.read((char*)&current_bite, sizeof(current_bite));
```

В первой строке считывание первого байта, во второй - второго. Потом опять в первой третьего, во второй четвертого...

Что написали - то и получается...

Comment: Точно. Спасибо большое, помог слепому!